# How to specify position for sorting icons in displaytag

Tags: java, css, jsp, jquery-ui-sortable, displaytag

I have sorted columns in displaytag using "sortable=true"....But I want to display the sorting icons at the extreme right of the column...How can I do this?
Here I have mentioned only one column for your reference...

```
<display:column  property="issuerName" scope="col" sortable="true" title="${issuerName}"  headerClass="hixTableHeader" class="displayTagtd" />
```

CSS code :

```
th.sortable a {
    background-image: url(../images/common/header/arrow_off.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:right;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right:25px;
    padding-left: 25px;

}

th.order1 a{
    background-image: url(../images/common/header/arrow_down.png);
    background-position:right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right:25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}

th.order2 a{
    background-image: url(../images/common/header/arrow_up.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-position:right;
    padding-right:25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting it on `<th>` instead of `<a>`. `<a>` is a `display:inline` element so it isn't stretching the whole size of the `<th>`.

```
th.sortable {
    background-image: url(../images/common/header/arrow_off.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:right;
}

th.order1 {
    background-image: url(../images/common/header/arrow_down.png);
    background-position:right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

th.order2 {
    background-image: url(../images/common/header/arrow_up.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:right;
}
```

Alternatively you could apply the following, this will have the `<a>` fill the `<th>` which is probably preferable as you will be able to click anywhere on the `<th>` to activate sorting.

```
th a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

### Update

Make sure you keep your current styles as well, to keep underlines you need to make sure it still targets your `<a>` tags. You can add this to target all `<a>` tags within `<th>` tags.

```
th a {
    text-underline:none;
}
```

Comment: It is working if I remove <a>...But the column headers are underlined after removing <a>....I have also set text-decoration as none...Even then the column headers are underlined....How can I remove the underline?

Comment: I'm not suggesting removing it from your original styles, you need to apply `text-decoration:none;` to your `a` elements or it will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

you might have to change the template file that contains the html code for `<display:column>`

Comment: Could you please be a bit more elaborate?

Comment: well i have been working with struts 2 tags where in each tag has a corresponding free marker template file that is used to render the tag as html content which is passed to the browser. In your case, display:column should be having one such template(may be in some other templating language). Now the issue is to position the image that comes along with the text in the column heading, so my guess is that you have to change the code in that template file to achieve the desired result.